# C-code, simple web server (Code OK)

Tags: c, linux, networking, web

I have a problem with my code about web server

```
#include<netinet/in.h>    
#include<stdio.h>    
#include<stdlib.h>    
#include<sys/socket.h>    
#include<sys/stat.h>    
#include<sys/types.h>    
#include<unistd.h>    

int main() {    
   int create_socket, new_socket;    
   socklen_t addrlen;    
   int bufsize = 1024;    
   char *buffer = malloc(bufsize);    
   struct sockaddr_in address;    

   if ((create_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) > 0){    
      printf("The socket was created\n");
   }

   address.sin_family = AF_INET;    
   address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;    
   address.sin_port = htons(15000);    

   if (bind(create_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &address, sizeof(address)) == 0){    
      printf("Binding Socket\n");
   }


   while (1) {    
      if (listen(create_socket, 10) < 0) {    
         perror("server: listen");    
         exit(1);    
      }    

      if ((new_socket = accept(create_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &address, &addrlen)) < 0) {    
         perror("server: accept");    
         exit(1);    
      }    

      if (new_socket > 0){    
         printf("The Client is connected...\n");
      }

      recv(new_socket, buffer, bufsize, 0);    
      printf("%s\n", buffer);    
      write(new_socket, "hello world\n", 12);    
      close(new_socket);    
   }    
   close(create_socket);    
   return 0;    
}
```

this is a little code to create a web server that at the port 15000 reply with "hello wordl" . Now i would that my server at a request (for example) "`http://127.0.0.1:15000/luigi`" reply with the text "luigi",that is with the phrase after " / ". Thanks!

Comment: What is the problem? What is the question?

Comment: this code is ok! But i would that when write for example "http://127.0.0.1:15000/start" reply with the phrase after /. Is it clear?

Comment: If i write "http://127.0.0.1:15000/luigi" reply luigi (at monitor). If i write "http://127.0.0.1:15000/finish" reply finish (at monitor)

Comment: what is need of writing like "127.0.0.1:15000...." in `write`.can you tell me?

Comment: Why don't you use some HTTP server library like [libonion](http://www.coralbits.com/libonion/) ? HTTP is quite a complex protocol to implement! Or at least `strace` some *simple* web server....

Comment: The question is that after " / " the text would be random , but the webserver would reply with the text after "/". I hope to be clear

Answer (score 2):

After **recv** function, you will have something like

```
GET /luigi HTTP/1.1
```

in `buffer`.This is the request sent by browser.
Text after `GET` is the relative url to your base address (127.0.0.1:15000). Now you can parse the buffer and do whatever you want.You can go to http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html for more details.

Comment: The question is that after "/" the text would be random. I would that my code reply (at monitor) with the same text (after /). i hope to be clear

Comment: The question is that after " / " the text would be random , but the webserver would reply with the text after "/". I hope to be clear

Comment: Whatever is the text after after "/", it will be there in request sent by browser just after "GET" keyword. Try "printf("%s", buffer);" after "recv" function, it will help you in understanding the request format.

Answer (score -1):

To add up to what user3864685 said, you can use 'strtok' function to get the string after "GET /".

Comment: -1. This is not a good form for an answer, this is more like a comment.

Comment: MY reputation is not '50' so I cannot comment to somebody's answer. Please do not down vote without knowing the issue, it's annoying! I just wanted to help up with some extra information and could not comment.

Comment: Ok, fair point I guess. Then you should delete or edit this answer to improve its quality. I can't remove the downvote unless the answer is edited (that's a SO policy/design, it's not my decision).